# Crontab not executing jobs Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to run bash script as a cron job every 15 minutes.

The bash script simple calls a Java program. I made an entry in crontab to run the file every 15 minutes and saved it but it would not do anything ?

crontab -e

```
*/15 * * * * /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/Run_Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.sh
```

Run_Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.sh

```
java Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite  >> Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.log
```

Comment: Are you sure "java" is in the PATH? (and I do not mean the users PATH ;-) )

Comment: I suggest you redirect std output and std error in order to debug your problem. `*/15 * * * * /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/Run_Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.sh >> /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/debug.log 2>&1`

Comment: Hi i tried this  ' /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite '  in the bash script now i get a n error  Could not find or load main class ?

Comment: Try to put your cron instructions in `/etc/crontab' instead of `crontab -e`

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible issues here. First of all, cron runs jobs in a special shell which does not read your personal $PATH. If `java` is not in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`, it will not be available to cron. From `man 5 crontab`:

> Several environment variables are set up automatically by  the 
>   cron(8)    daemon.  SHELL is set to /bin/sh, and LOGNAME and HOME are
>   set from the    /etc/passwd  line  of   the   crontab's   owner.
>   **PATH   is   set   to    "/usr/bin:/bin".**   HOME,  SHELL, and PATH may
>   be overridden by settings    in the crontab; LOGNAME is the user that
>   the job is running  from,  and    may not be changed.

So, use the full path to `java` instead. The next issue is that your bash script calls java on a file with a relative path. It assumes that the script will be launched from the same directory as the java file. Again, this is not the case. So, always use absolute paths for your scripts if you want them to run as expected by cron:

```
/path/to/java /path/to/Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite  >> /path/to/Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.log
```

Alternatively, you can set the `$PATH` in the crontab itself:

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin

*/15 * * * * /home/marshell/graphite_cronjobs/Run_Cron_Read_Send_CapacityData_To_Graphite.sh
```

Comment: It is also possible to put a PATH in crontab ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind yes but personally I find using full paths better. In any case they're needed for the input and output files here. Still, I added an example of setting the path in the crontab.